# "distinct" query returning me multiple records

Tags: sql, psql

On executing the following query I am getting multiple records as result with each having id=10. If I am using distinct keyword, then I should get just one record. What could be the cause?

> "select distinct(id) from tablename where id="10"

Answer (score 1):

You really should provide some test data, and let us know which SQL you are using (TSQL/MySQL/psql).  By your tags, I assume your using psql.

Acording to [the Postgres Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html) you should do something like this:

```
select distinct id from tablename where id="10"
```

This will just return one row/col that contains 10 if there is one in your table, if you want all the different varieties of rows where id="10" in your table without any duplicates, than you can do:

```
select distinct * from tablename where id="10"
```

Your syntax appears to be calling distinct as a function, not an sql keyword look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408037/distinct-function-not-select-qualifier-in-postgres)

Also, if "id" is really an id for your rows, perhaps you should consider making it a primary key.  Then there will only be one row with that value allowed in the table.